# PySpark: DataFrame - Convert Struct to Array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in the following structure:

```
root
 |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topicDistribution: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- wiki_index: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to change it to:

```
root
 |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topicDistribution: array (nullable = true)
 |    |--  element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- wiki_index: string (nullable = true)
```

May I ask how can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
df.withColumn("topicDistribution", col("topicDistribution").getField("values"))
```

Comment: This is an interesting use case and solution. However, the `topicDistribution` column remains of type `struct` and not `array` and I have not yet figured out how to convert between these two types.

Comment: How can this be done dynamically . my withColumn should dynamically create all the columsn based on column name of keys ?

Comment: I don't have code on hand, but you can do something like:
1. `struct_keys = ...## go through schema to figure out the column keys`
2. `new_cols = [col("yourStruct").getField(kk) for kk in struct_keys]`
3. `df.select(*(new_cols + orig_cols))`

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding full working code for some peoples who wants to understand whole working code examples.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType, ArrayType, DoubleType

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a Spark session
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

    # Define the schema
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("index", LongType(), True),
        StructField("text", StringType(), True),
        StructField("topicDistribution", StructType([
            StructField("type", LongType(), True),
            StructField("values", ArrayType(DoubleType()), True)
        ]), True),
        StructField("wiki_index", StringType(), True)
    ])

    # Sample data
    data = [
        (1, "Sample Text 1", (100, [0.3, 0.5, 0.2]), "wiki_1"),
        (2, "Sample Text 2", (101, [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]), "wiki_2"),
        (3, "Sample Text 3", (102, [0.6, 0.2, 0.2]), "wiki_3")
    ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

    # Accessing the 'values' array within 'topicDistribution'
    df_values = df.withColumn("topicDistribution",col("topicDistribution.values"))
    df_values.printSchema()
    df_values.show(truncate=False)
```