# Convert multiple array of structs columns in pyspark sql

Tags: python, struct, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe with multiple columns (Around 30) of nested structs, that I want to write into csv. (struct

In order to do it, I want to stringify all of the struct columns.

I've checked several answers here:

[Pyspark converting an array of struct into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381557/pyspark-converting-an-array-of-struct-into-string)

[PySpark: DataFrame - Convert Struct to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616606/pyspark-dataframe-convert-struct-to-array)

[PySpark convert struct field inside array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343635/pyspark-convert-struct-field-inside-array-to-string)

This is the structure of my dataframe (with around 30 complex keys):

```
root  
 |-- 1_simple_key: string (nullable = true)  
 |-- 2_simple_key: string (nullable = true)  
 |-- 3_complex_key: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n1: string (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n2: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n3: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n4: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n5: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n6: long (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n7: long (nullable = true)  
 |-- 4_complex_key: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n1: string (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n2: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n3: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n4: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n5: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n6: long (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n7: long (nullable = true)  
 |-- 5_complex_key: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n1: string (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n2: struct (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n3: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n4: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |    |-- n5: boolean (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n6: long (nullable = true)  
 |    |-- n7: long (nullable = true)
```

The proposed solutions are for a single column, and I can't adopt it to multiple columns.

I want to do something of this type:
1. For each struct_column:
2. col = stringify(struct_column)

I don't mind creating an additional dataframe for it. I just need to make it ready for csv writing.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
d = d = {'1_complex_key': {0: Row(type='1_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=954, y=238), 1: Row(type='1_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=956, y=250), 2: Row(type='1_complex_key', s=Row(n1=True, n2=False, n3=False), x=886, y=269)}, '2_complex_key': {0: Row(type='2_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=901, y=235), 1: Row(type='2_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=905, y=249), 2: Row(type='2_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=868, y=270)}, '3_complex_key': {0: Row(type='3_complex_key', s=Row(n1=True, n2=False, n3=False), x=925, y=197), 1: Row(type='3_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=928, y=206), 2: Row(type='3_complex_key', s=Row(n1=False, n2=False, n3=True), x=883, y=236)}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
s_df.printSchema()
s_df.write.csv('it_doesnt_write.csv')
```

[image]
[image]

So - to summarize: 
I have a spark dataframe that I want to write to CSV.
I can't write it to CSV because:

```
'CSV data source does not support struct<s:struct<n1:boolean,n2:boolean,n3:boolean>,type:string,x:bigint,y:bigint> data type.;'
```

So I want to perform some actions / reversible transformations on this dataframe so that I can write it to CSV, and later read it from the CSV and make it a spark dataframe with the same schema.

How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Use a list comprehension over the `struct` columns as shown in [Apply a transformation to multiple columns pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452076/apply-a-transformation-to-multiple-columns-pyspark-dataframe). For a more detailed answer, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hey. I've added the extract structure. I've seen your answer, but how can I stringify this struct object in order to write it to csv later? And be able to reconstruct it? 

I want to be able to write it to CSV and then read it from the CSV and transform it to pyspark again.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and someone will answer your question.

Comment: @cronoik it was hard, but here is a minimal reproducible example :)

Answer (score 1):

As [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595189/convert-multiple-array-of-structs-columns-in-pyspark-sql?noredirect=1#comment103503543_58595189) has already mentioned in the comments, you need a list comprehension. Such a list comprehension requires a list of columns and a functions which converts this columns to strings. I will use `df.columns` and [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json) but you can also provide your own python list of column names and a custom function to stringfy your complex columns.

```py
#this converts all columns to json strings
#and writes it as to disk
s_df.select([F.to_json(x) for x in s_df.columns]).coalesce(1).write.csv('/tmp/testcsv')
```

In case you don't want to apply to_json to all columns, you can simply modify it like that:

```py
list4tojson = ['2_complex_key', '3_complex_key']
s_df.select('1_complex_key', *[F.to_json(x) for x in list4tojson]).coalesce(1).write.csv('/tmp/testcsv')
```

You can restore dataframe with [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json):

```
df = spark.read.csv('/tmp/testcsv')
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
# |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
# |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)

#interfering the schema
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row._c0)).schema

df.select([F.from_json(x, json_schema) for x in df.columns] ).printSchema()
#root
# |-- jsontostructs(_c0): struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- s: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n1: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n2: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n3: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
# |-- jsontostructs(_c1): struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- s: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n1: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n2: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n3: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
# |-- jsontostructs(_c2): struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- s: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n1: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n2: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- n3: boolean (nullable = true)
# |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
```

In case you just want to store your data in a readable format, you can avoid all of the above code by writing it to json directly:

```py
s_df.coalesce(1).write.json('/tmp/testjson')

df = spark.read.json('/tmp/testjson')
```