# How to json.loads with custom separator in python?

Tags: python, json, pyspark, decode

TLDR: How can I json.loads with custom separator without replacing the separator with a comma?

I have a spark dataframe, that I want to write to CSV, and for that I need to jsonize every row in it.

So I have the following pyspark row:

```
Row(type='le', v=Row(occ=False, oov=False, v=True), x=966, y=340)
```

I want to make the row ready for CSV. 
If I write to CSV with normal json.dumps, I will get line with many commas, then the read csv method doesn't read the file (a lot more commas)

So, I perform json.dumps with separators=("| ", ": ")), and I get the string s:

```
'["le"| [false| false| true]| 966| 340]'
```

Now i'm able to do:

```
json.loads(s.replace('|',','))
```

And I receive the desired output:

```
['le', [False, False, True], 966, 340]
```

Now is the problematic part:

I write it to csv. When I read it, before trying to json.loads, I receive:

```
'[\\le\\"| [false| false| true]| 966| 340]"'
```

The desired output, is as before:

```
['le', [False, False, True], 966, 340]
```

But I can't reach it.

When I try to do json.loads, I get:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

When I try to change the '|' to ',':

```
s = s.replace('|',',')
s
Out: '[\\left_ear\\", [false, false, true], 966, 340]"'
json.loads(s)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

This post is a try to overcome a previous problem which I didn't find answer to:
[Convert multiple array of structs columns in pyspark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595189/convert-multiple-array-of-structs-columns-in-pyspark-sql?noredirect=1#comment103508770_58595189)

If I find a solution to this problem it will help me.

Bottom line this is the line I need to parse:

```
'[\\le\\"| [false| false| true]| 966| 340]"'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why are you using `separators` to generate invalid JSON in the first place?

Comment: If I write to CSV with normal json.dumps, I will get line with many commas, then the read csv method doesn't read the file (a lot more commas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a spark DataFrame as csv on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174443/how-to-save-a-spark-dataframe-as-csv-on-disk)

Comment: `json.dumps` isn't writing CSV *at all*; at best, your quasi-JSON will pass as valid CSV input, but I wouldn't count on it. I would look into avoiding JSON altogether, and getting a `list` (or something that the `csv` module can handle) directly from your data frame.

Comment: @GSazheniuk sadly no, I don't have write permissions on that server, I can only create CSV and get download it for it.

Comment: @chepner I prefer to use something more interpretable like dictionary...

Comment: Use whatever *data structure* you want; just don't use JSON as the middleman for converting that to CSV.

Comment: @chepner it has to go through json: even if I try a list, it is saved as spark's array and therefore it can't be exported to CSV. So it can't remain a complex datatype therefore it must transform to string...